# How can I run a python script with out the prompt "Run in terminal, Display, cancel, Run"

Tags: python, scripts, automatic

I added `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the script and `chmod +x` in terminal, but on double clicking it still asks for these 4 options.

I want it to automatically open in terminal. Is it possible? I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 4):

You can change this behavior in the preferences of Nautilus (*Files* in the dash).

On the tab *Behavior* under *Executable Text Files*.

[image: Files Preferences]

Note this changes the behavior for **all** excutable text files.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to define a `.desktop` file to run your python application in a terminal on double click on this `.desktop` file.

This would be a basic content needed:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=python /full/path/to/script/script.py
Icon=/path/to/icon # only if needed
Name=Name of script
Terminal=true
```

Save this anywhere (putting in `~/.local/share/applications/` will also make it executable from the Dash etc.) as `name-of-script.desktop` and give it executable permission.