# Kubuntu no hibernation button/settings in KDE

Tags: dual-boot, kde, hibernate

I am using Kubuntu 20.04 with a swap partition and can use the terminal to hibernate my pc:

```
$ sudo systemctl hibernate
```

However I want to be able to use "Power management" and KDE UI to use hibernation.
[Power settings(no hibernation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45GxC.png)

I have created a swap partition with 17G while I have 16G ram.

```
$ swapon --show
NAME           TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/nvme0n1p6 partition  17G   0B   -2
```

Disk setup

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.96 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVLB512HBJQ-000L2              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FA9C3C18-0928-43EA-8E49-767C04AF89DC

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    567296  486166527 485599232 231.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 998166528 1000214527   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 486166528  962514943 476348416 227.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6 962514944  998164479  35649536    17G Linux swap
```

If there is any more information I need to provide please let me know and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others having this problem hibernation might just be deactivated in Ubuntu(even when having enough swap), because of problems with some hardware using hibernation.

You can follow this guide to enable it:
[How to Enable Hibernate in Ubuntu Linux](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-enable-hibernate-in-ubuntu-linux)

**Enable Hibernate in System Menu** - from guide

The indicator-session was updated to use logind instead of upower. Hibernate is disabled by default in both upower and logind.

Run the following commands to enable hibernate.

```
$ sudo -i
$ cd /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/
$ gedit com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

Tips: if the config file does not work for you, try another one by changing /var/lib to /etc in the code.

Copy and paste the below lines to the file and save it.

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Log out or Restart your system and you’ve done. After you login, you’ll see hibernate option in your system Menu above in the tray.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help, if you are unable to find the hibernate button.

1. Create a python file on desktop and name it something convenient like `hibernate.py`.
2. Paste the following code into the file and save it

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os  
os.system("sudo systemctl hibernate")
```

3. Go to terminal and navigate to that folder and then run `chmod 700 hibernate.py`.
4. Now to hibernate just double click on the file `hibernate.py`, and it will hibernate.

So basically we made the script executable and double clicking the file will run the part inside the `os.system` parenthesis in terminal, which will hibernate the PC.

If you want to store this executable file somewhere else and access it with a shortcut somewhere on the desktop, you could try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/293660/1067851) answer.

Comment: Thanks Abhay but I am looking for a native/integrated solution as there is a settings/setup I am missing I would presume